# Change expander's background color during collapsed

Tags: wpf

is it possible to change the Expander background color during collapsed ?

Answer (score 0):

[`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) & [`Trigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Trigger.aspx) (watch the [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) though).